# unsupported charset "ISO-8859-1" in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

In my nodeJS application I used following line of code to get req.body

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
```

This is working fine, but one request to my application throws following error:

```
UnsupportedMediaTypeError: unsupported charset "ISO-8859-1"
    at urlencodedParser (/var/www/payment/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:108:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/payment/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/payment/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /var/www/payment/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/var/www/payment/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/var/www/payment/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (/var/www/payment/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:118:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/payment/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/payment/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /var/www/payment/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

If I remove the previous line, then it works for that request, but in all other requests, I am unable to retrieve data. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the original request header, to UTF-8.

I found no easy way to intercept the urlencoded parser, so i just changed the encoding to utf8

Comment: server.use((...args) => {
        if (args[0].headers['content-type']?.includes('charset=ISO-8859-1')) {
            args[0].headers['content-type'] = args[0].headers[
                'content-type'
            ].replace('charset=ISO-8859-1', 'charset=UTF-8');
        }
        return bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })(...args);
    });

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for the code snippet. I made a small change for using it with Express 4: replacing `bodyParser` with `express`.